# Создание списка из полей и ключей многомерного массива

Tags: массивы, javascript

Добрый вечер! Решаю проблему формирования списка-дерева.

Имеется к примеру такой массив:

```
$mas = array ( "City"  => array ( "a" => "New-York",
                                   "b" => "London",
                                   "c" => "Moscow"
                                 ),
              "Numbers"   => array ( "element-1",
                                   "element-2",
                                   "element-3",
                                   "element-4",
                                   "element-5",
                                   "element-6"
                                 ),
              "Other"   => array (      "one",
                                    5 => "two",
                                         "three",
                    7=> array ("mas10", "mas15")    
                                 )
            );
```

После преобразования в JSON-формат массив выглядит так:

```
{
"City":{"a":"New-York","b":"London","c":"Moscow"},
 "Numbers" ["element-1","element-2","element-3","element-4","element-5","element-6"],
 "Other":{"0":"one","5":"two","6":"three","7":["mas10","mas15"]}
}
```

Через JSON я передаю его в JS-код, в котором есть функция проставляющая теги списка:

```
function Dump(d,l) 
    {
      if (l == null) l = 1;
      var s = '';
      if (typeof(d) == "object") 
      {
        s += "<li><img src='../images/folder.gif' />";
        for (var k in d) 
        {

          s += "<ul>" + Dump(d[k],l+1)+"</ul>";

        }
        s += "</li>";
      } 
      else 
      {
        s += "<li><img src='../images/file.gif' />" + d + "</li>";
      }
      return s;
    }

str = Dump(data,1);
$("#span2").html(str);
```

И все это дело формируется в таком виде:
http://www.imgup.ru/image-12jrx7161953.html

А хотелось бы сделать так чтобы заголовки элементов которые являются массивами в свою очередь (как например "City" или "7") показывали свои заголовки, а элементы которые просто хранят значения не показывали свои заголовки (такие как ключ "a", "5" или просто значения без указанного ключа как к примеру "element-3", "mas15" и т.д.). Как это сделать? Пробовал выводить значения k в цикле, но оно выводит аболютно все ключи, даже которые не являются массивами.

Comment: json в виде строки положите сюда, для удобства.

Comment: Тоесть как преобразовать в строку, а потом ее разбирать по косточкам? Мне кажется это еще сложнее будет. Просто не знаю как различить ключи содержащие массив и содержащие просто значения. Тут нужно одно условие добавить, если ключ содержит подмассив, то вывести название ключа, в противном случае опустить его имя. Есть такая функция в JS? Подскажите, эксперты!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допилил свой код следующим образом:

```
function Dump(d,l,name) 
        {
          if (l == null) l = 1;
          var s = '';
          if (typeof(d) == "object") 
          {
            s += "<li><img src='../images/folder.gif' />"+name;
            for (var k in d) 
            {

              s += "<ul>" + Dump(d[k],l+1,k)+"</ul>";

            }
            s += "</li>";
          } 
          else 
          {
            s += "<li><img src='../images/file.gif' />" + d + "</li>";
          }
          return s;
        }

    str = Dump(data,1, "Корень");
    $("#span2").html(str);
```

И теперь структура JSON полученная из php-файла имеет следующий вид, какой мне и нужно было: http://www.imgup.ru/image-12knx501155.html

Answer (score 0):

Если в `JS` приходит ваш JSON уже готовый? то я бы посоветовал бы вам использовать такую конструкцию перебора массива на jQuery

```
var URL = 'file.json'

$.getJSON(URL,
    function(result){
        $.each(result, 
            function(key, value){
                // Здесь мы получим три значения результат => ключ => значение
            }
        )
    }
)
```

> Прошу не пинать, может я не так понял
> ваш вопрос.

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет! Я вначале тоже так использовал $.each для перебора элементов массива, к сожалению такой метот не учитывает уровня вложенности значения (т.к. у меня многомерные и многоуровневые массивы). И потом мне приходится различать ключи которые содержат подмассивы и ключи которые содержат просто значения, потому это не подходит к сожалению.